# Docker Alpine /bin/sh apk not found

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I am building a new Docker image with:

```
FROM alpine:3.4
RUN apk upgrade --update
```

However, its failing with the error:

```
[INFO] /bin/sh: apk: not found
```

This seems to work fine on my local machine (Mac OSX) but when I try building it on a Linux CentOS 7 machine it fails.

Comment: Can you check `docker images` and check the ID of `alpine:3.4`? On a fresh Docker host I get `baa5d63471ea`.

Comment: I can confirm that docker images returns baa5d63471ea also for me

Comment: Odd. What do you see from `docker run alpine:3.4 which apk`

Comment: I see - /sbin/apk

Comment: Odd. `docker version`?

Comment: Currently using: 1.10.3

Comment: I'm thinking now that it might be due to the Maven plugin we are using to build our images (https://github.com/alexec/docker-maven-plugin).

I did a docker build and it works okay.

Comment: Could be. Try this: `mvn <goals> -Ddocker.cache=false` (from the [DEBUG](https://github.com/alexec/docker-maven-plugin/blob/master/DEBUG.md) page to make sure there's not a bad image cached.

Comment: Just gave it a try, still giving me the same error

Comment: @MikeChinaloy Did you find its answer? I am also facing same issue.

Comment: @jass I fixed this by using a more recent version of the docker-maven-plugin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [/bin/sh: 1: apk: not found while creating docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40445243/bin-sh-1-apk-not-found-while-creating-docker-image)

Comment: @MikeChinaloy which filesystem your partition is formatted?

Comment: @MikeChinaloy you should post an answer to your own question with your solution and accept it

Comment: @Thomasleveil done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end we upgraded our projects to use this Docker Maven plugin: https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-maven-plugin. No issue thus far.

Comment: Could you detail how it solved your issue? It's not obvious but I'm curious since I have the same original issue :)

Answer (score 10):

I ran into something like this.  It completely blew my mind, and I was questioning my sanity for a bit until I realized that `/sbin` wasn't in my container's `PATH`.

```
# interactive session
PATH="${PATH}:/sbin"

# Dockerfile
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/sbin"
```

If you type `command -v apk` in an interactive session in your container's base image and compare that directory with the container's `$PATH` that should get you squared away.

If `command -v apk` doesn't work for you, you could try to `find` it via

```
find / -name apk -type f -exec dirname "{}" ";"
```

To the best of my knowledge this is always in `/sbin`. However you get there, just ensure that the `apk` binary's location is part of `$PATH`

TL;DR - If you see this error, ensure that your executable's `dirname` is in your `$PATH`

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks! `/sbin` was not in the path for me, either.

Comment: docker 10.10.17, is alpine 3.15 image, no apk, sbin is empty.  it may be because the client cleaned it out, its a client image, and it prob was stripped to bare essentials(partially even for security), would this make sense?  this is a prometheus only image also, if that rings any bells to anyone .  EDIT, maybe this isnt alpine, and no -release file anywhere.. (no apk,yum,apt,dnf,pacman,etc..)