# /bin/sh: 1: apk: not found while creating docker image

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dockerfile, apt

I have the below Dockerfile for zookeeper and I am trying to create an image for it, but it is giving me an error. I have recently started working with Docker, and started playing with a Zookeeper setup, so I am not able to understand. What does this error mean?

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
MAINTAINER David

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jre-headless wget
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

# Install required packages
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    bash \
    su-exec

ENV ZOO_USER=zookeeper \
    ZOO_CONF_DIR=/conf \
    ZOO_DATA_DIR=/data \
    ZOO_DATA_LOG_DIR=/datalog \
    ZOO_PORT=2181 \
    ZOO_TICK_TIME=2000 \
    ZOO_INIT_LIMIT=5 \
    ZOO_SYNC_LIMIT=2

# Add a user and make dirs
RUN set -x \
    && adduser -D "$ZOO_USER" \
    && mkdir -p "$ZOO_DATA_LOG_DIR" "$ZOO_DATA_DIR" "$ZOO_CONF_DIR" \
    && chown "$ZOO_USER:$ZOO_USER" "$ZOO_DATA_LOG_DIR" "$ZOO_DATA_DIR" "$ZOO_CONF_DIR"

ARG GPG_KEY=C823E3E5B12AF29C67F81976F5CECB3CB5E9BD2D
ARG DISTRO_NAME=zookeeper-3.4.9

# Download Apache Zookeeper, verify its PGP signature, untar and clean up
RUN set -x \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        gnupg \
    && wget -q "http://www.apache.org/dist/zookeeper/$DISTRO_NAME/$DISTRO_NAME.tar.gz" \
    && wget -q "http://www.apache.org/dist/zookeeper/$DISTRO_NAME/$DISTRO_NAME.tar.gz.asc" \
    && export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)" \
    && gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key "$GPG_KEY" \
    && gpg --batch --verify "$DISTRO_NAME.tar.gz.asc" "$DISTRO_NAME.tar.gz" \
    && tar -xzf "$DISTRO_NAME.tar.gz" \
    && mv "$DISTRO_NAME/conf/"* "$ZOO_CONF_DIR" \
    && rm -r "$GNUPGHOME" "$DISTRO_NAME.tar.gz" "$DISTRO_NAME.tar.gz.asc" \
    && apk del .build-deps

WORKDIR $DISTRO_NAME
VOLUME ["$ZOO_DATA_DIR", "$ZOO_DATA_LOG_DIR"]

EXPOSE $ZOO_PORT 2888 3888

ENV PATH=$PATH:/$DISTRO_NAME/bin \
    ZOOCFGDIR=$ZOO_CONF_DIR

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["zkServer.sh", "start-foreground"]
```

Below is the error I got:

```
Step 4 : ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
 ---> Running in a49507cb9725
 ---> 77b37883caf4
Removing intermediate container a49507cb9725
Step 5 : RUN apk add --no-cache     bash     su-exec
 ---> Running in a4fd76a644cf
/bin/sh: 1: apk: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache     bash     su-exec' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? Why is `apk` not found?

Comment: `apk` is the package manager for Alpine.  You're using Ubuntu.  You need to use `apt-get`.

Comment: [This](https://sookocheff.com/post/docker/containerizing-zookeeper-a-guided-tour/) looks like an article that might be very apropos to what you're trying to do.

Comment: @larsks thanks for pointing out the mistake. So you are saying I should replace `apk` with `apt-get` in my Dockerfile and it should work? I want to keep my FROM tag as it is.

Comment: I want to use trusty image to make it work.

Comment: for Alpine users `RUN apk update` works but `RUN "apk update"` does not...

Answer (score 79):

As [larsks mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40445243/bin-sh-1-apk-not-found-while-creating-docker-image#comment68137362_40445243), `apk` is for Alpine distributions and you selected `FROM ubuntu:trusty` which is Debian based with the `apt-get` command. Change your FROM line to `FROM alpine:3.4` to switch to the Alpine based image with `apk` support.

Comment: aahh now I understood. But let's say I want to keep `FROM ubuntu:trusty` line then what I need to change? So I should replace `apk` with `apt-get` everywhere in my Dockerfile to make it work?

Comment: Changing to a different packaging tool that's pointing to it's own repositories means a different syntax and different package names. [larsks's second link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40445243/bin-sh-1-apk-not-found-while-creating-docker-image/40445482?noredirect=1#comment68137377_40445243) provides the answer for that.

Comment: is it possible to install apk manager on ubuntu?

Comment: @user732456 that would have the same effect as installing Windows 95 and NT on the same C drive. These are different distributions, different (incompatible) libraries, what would happen when one package manager overwrites the files installed by the other?

Comment: I can imagine that it's not a brilliant idea, but I needed for testing purposes only. Also once I gave my Mac to our admin for installation and if I recall it right I ended up with apt-get on my computer alongside with brew. So my guess was that although it's not a good practice it's not impossible.

Comment: I still get: Step 4/18 : RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp gcc libc-dev linux-headers
 ---> Running in 00068e9429e6
/bin/sh: apk: not found
ERROR: Service 'django_app' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp gcc libc-dev linux-headers' returned a non-zero code: 127

Answer (score 21):

Quite late to the party. I'll put down what worked for me.

As [john](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2809564/john) rightly pointed out that apk is package manager for alpine distributions, for ubuntu image, we need to use apt-get:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tini
```

Otherwise Alpine base image can be used to run apk commands:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine3.12
RUN apk add --no-cache tini
```