# How to install Alpine Linux packages in the gliderlabs/alpine Docker image, when apk add fails?

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I want to install Alpine packages like python in a Docker image, but when I run [`docker build - < Dockerfile`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) (or build using IntelliJ) I get

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  /bin/sh (virtual):
    provided by: busybox
    required by:
                 alpine-baselayout-3.1.0-r0[/bin/sh]
                 alpine-baselayout-3.1.0-r0[/bin/sh]
The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --update python' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

I am using the following Dockerfile which I derived from the docs at [github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/blob/master/docs/usage.md](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/blob/master/docs/usage.md#example)

```
FROM gliderlabs/alpine:latest
RUN apk add --update python
```

**Same error when using the docker image interactively**

When I use `docker run -it gliderlabs/alpine:latest /bin/sh` and then `apk add --update python` or `apk add python` I get the same error.

When I do `apk update` I get `OK: 9543 distinct packages available`, but when I do `apk upgrade` I get the same error.

#### System information

I am using Arch Linux 4.19.8.

The Image ID of gliderlabs/alpine:latest is `sha256:673b8178133a04ed1de21d6cf1a729f8aaf9469d4550005ede89e7142efd9459`.

The output of `docker run gliderlabs/alpine:latest which apk` is `/sbin/apk`.

The docker version is 18.09.0-ce.

#### Relevant other information

[Docker Alpine /bin/sh apk not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40264279/docker-alpine-bin-sh-apk-not-found) looks similar (though on CentOS) but has no resolution, one comment links to:

[/bin/sh: 1: apk: not found while creating docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40445243/bin-sh-1-apk-not-found-while-creating-docker-image) but the answer is to switch to `apk` which I'm doing already (the docs are pretty clear about this).

[Docker: Using apt-key with alpine image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515863/docker-using-apt-key-with-alpine-image) also suggests to use `apk add` which is what I'm doing.

**Edit**

As suggested by @larsks, you can run `apk search --update python | grep '^python'` and it shows me that I have `python3-3.6.6-r0` availabe but not `python`. However, when I try `apk add python3-3.6.6-r0` I get

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  python3-3.6.6-r0 (missing):
    required by: world[python3-3.6.6-r0]
  /bin/sh (virtual):
    provided by: busybox
    required by: alpine-baselayout-3.1.0-r0[/bin/sh] alpine-baselayout-3.1.0-r0[/bin/sh]
```

Also, this wouldn't explain why `apk upgrade` fails with the same error as `apk add python`.

When I try `apk add --update python3` I get

```
fetch http://alpine.gliderlabs.com/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://alpine.gliderlabs.com/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  /bin/sh (virtual):
    provided by: busybox
    required by: alpine-baselayout-3.1.0-r0[/bin/sh] alpine-baselayout-3.1.0-r0[/bin/sh]
```

Comment: Use the `alpine` image instead of `gliderlabs/alpine`.

Comment: @larsks Yes, that was the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `python` package available in current Alpine images.  If you take a look at the output of `apk search --update python`, you'll find:

```
/ # apk search python | grep '^python'
[...]
python2-2.7.15-r1
python3-3.6.6-r0
[...]
```

That is, you will need to explicitly install either `python2` or `python3` depending on which version you want.

So with the latest Alpine image (3.8), I can successfully install `python3` by running:

```
/ # apk add --update python3
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/11) Installing libbz2 (1.0.6-r6)
(2/11) Installing expat (2.2.5-r0)
(3/11) Installing libffi (3.2.1-r4)
(4/11) Installing gdbm (1.13-r1)
(5/11) Installing xz-libs (5.2.4-r0)
(6/11) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.1_p20180818-r1)
(7/11) Installing ncurses-terminfo (6.1_p20180818-r1)
(8/11) Installing ncurses-libs (6.1_p20180818-r1)
(9/11) Installing readline (7.0.003-r0)
(10/11) Installing sqlite-libs (3.24.0-r0)
(11/11) Installing python3 (3.6.6-r0)
Executing busybox-1.28.4-r1.trigger
OK: 67 MiB in 24 packages
```

The second problem you've reported appears to stem from the fact that you're using the `gliderlabs/alpine` image rather than the official `alpine` images.  I see the same problem if I use `gliderlabs/alpine`, but everything works using `alpine`.  The `gliderlabs/alpine` image appears to be bad.

Comment: Oh, strange that the [docs](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/blob/master/docs/usage.md#example) don't show this, but if I do `apk add python3-3.6.6-r0` I get a similar error, namely `ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints: python3-3.6.6-r0 (missing): required by: world[python3-3.6.6-r0]`  Also, this wouldn't explain why `apk upgrade` fails as well. I'll add this new error to the question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `apk` doesn't support the syntax you're tring to use.  Just run `apk add --update python3`.

Comment: You mean the upgrade syntax? When I run `apk` it shows me `upgrade` under System maintenance, and I saw it elsewhere as well. Anyway, when I try `python3` still the same error, see question.

Comment: I meant that I don't think you can specify the package as `python3-3.6.6-r0`.

Comment: Yes agree, but the real problem seemed to be the image, the docs must be mistaken or something. Thanks!

Comment: PS using the alpine docker image, `apk add python` works, it just installs python 2. So the only problem was the image. Note that somewhere else [in their docs](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/blob/master/docs/build.md#differences) they actually say to use the `alpine` and not the `gliderlabs/alpine` image.