# node:latest for alpine, apk not found because sbin is not on path

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am running a docker-compose file using node:latest.  I noticed an issue with the timezone that I am trying to fix.  Following an example I found online, I tried to install tzdata.  This is not working as I keep getting apk not found errors. After finding this stackoverflow.com question, [Docker Alpine /bin/sh apk not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40264279/docker-alpine-bin-sh-apk-not-found), it seems to mirror my issue as I docker exec'ed into the container and found the apk command in the /sbin folder.  I tried to do the following to make it work but I am still not able to access apk.  From other articles I found, this seemed to be the way to resolve the issue but apk is still not found.

```
CMD export PATH=$PATH:$ADDITIONAL_PATH
RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata
ENV TZ=America/Chicago
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`node:latest` is based on `buildpack-deps`, which is based on Debian. Debian does not use `apk`; it uses `apt`. You either want to use Debian's `apt` to install packages (`apt-get install tzdata`) or switch to `node:alpine`, which uses `apk` for package management.

Comment: I get this error this time, ERROR: Dockerfile parse error line 16: unknown instruction: APT-GET.  The weird thing is that when I went into the console earlier to check the os version, I see Alpine listed even though I am running node:latest.

Comment: Make sure to prefix the apt-get command with RUN in your Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`node:alpine`](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/a9c583095d4cf08bbd68f570a1f9a99780820351/8/alpine/Dockerfile) which is based on alpine.

```
node:alpine
CMD export PATH=$PATH:$ADDITIONAL_PATH
RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata
ENV TZ=America/Chicago
```

**node:-alpine**

> This image is based on the popular Alpine Linux project, available in
>   the alpine official image. Alpine Linux is much smaller than most
>   distribution base images **(~5MB)**, and thus leads to much slimmer images
>   in general.